# Is there a way to have a non-column key exist in my strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently writing some endpoints for my Rails 6 API.

One problem that I'm currently runnning into is that when I'm making a POST request, I'm sending in a key that doesn't actually exist on the model. It shows up in my `params`, but is there a way for it to show up in the model params as well?

Example

```
{
    "comment": "Test",
    "name": "Test",
    "age": 50
}
```

Is there a way for it to include the `comment` param when I call `params[model_name]`?

I tried adding it into my permitted params, but had no luck. I also added it as an `attr_accessor` and it didn't work either.

Comment: We could really do with seeing more of your actual params, and your view with the definition in it

Answer (score 0):

You're making a faulty assumption here that there is a connection between the Strong Parameters API and the model when no such connection actually exists.[`ActionController::Parameters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) is really just a hash like object with a few extra tricks up its sleeve for slicing and dicing. It doesn't have any knowledge of the model.

The only thing that links the two is convention as in Rails the models internals (the database columns) are often the same as the parameters of the endpoint.

When you pass an instance of
`ActionController::Parameters` to a model [`ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html) checks if the attributes are `permitted?` and then loops through the keys and values and calls the corresponding setter method for each key in the input.

If there is no corresponding method an error is raised.

If you want to be able to assign attributes that are not backed by a database column all you need to do is provide a setter. This can be done via the [attributes API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :bar, :integer
end
```

This will behave just like other attributes and will for example be included when serializing the record. If you don't want/need that just use the plain old setters that defined via `attr_writer`.